# Desctuction of object is causing the crash of the program

Tags: c++, destructor

Here is a snippet of a considerably big C++ program:

```
map<int, int>::iterator class_it = docsCountPerClass.begin();
for( ;class_it !=  docsCountPerClass.end(); class_it++) {
    cout << "classid: " << class_it->first << '\n';
    vector<term_importance> ti;
    ti.reserve(termids.size());
    vector<int>::iterator term_it = termids.begin();
    for( ;(term_it != termids.end()); term_it++) {
        term_importance tmp;
        tmp.termid = *term_it;
        tmp.importnaceMeasure = chiSquareTest(*term_it, class_it->first);
        ti.push_back(tmp);
    }
    if(ti.size() != 0)
        std::sort(ti.begin(), ti.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < ti.size(); i++)
        cout << (ti.at(i)).termid << " -- " << (ti.at(i)).importnaceMeasure << '\n';
    int ti_size_tmp = ti.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < std::min(maxFeaturesPerClass, int(ti.size()) ); i++) {
        cout << "* index access: " << ti_size_tmp - 1 - i << '\n';
        usefulTerms[class_it->first].push_back( (ti.at(ti_size_tmp - 1 - i)).termid );
    }
```

The problem I am facing when the loop completes its cycle and returns the vector ti should destruct. It does but while cleaning up the objects inside it it crashes, and it reports that its trying to call free() on invalid pointer.. I am unable to reproduce the problem using simpler code. Here is the backtrace using gdb:

```
#0  0x0012d422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00341651 in *__GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#2  0x00344a82 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#3  0x0037849d in __libc_message (do_abort=2, fmt=0x44cf98 "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:189
#4  0x00382591 in malloc_printerr (action=<value optimized out>, str=0x6 <Address 0x6 out of bounds>, ptr=0x81dc5e0) at malloc.c:6264
#5  0x00383de8 in _int_free (av=<value optimized out>, p=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:4792
#6  0x00386ecd in *__GI___libc_free (mem=0x81dc5e0) at malloc.c:3738
#7  0x00297741 in operator delete(void*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x08054377 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<NaiveBayesClassifier::term_importance>::deallocate (this=0xbffff194, __p=0x81dc5e0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/new_allocator.h:95
#9  0x080522db in std::_Vector_base<NaiveBayesClassifier::term_importance, std::allocator<NaiveBayesClassifier::term_importance> >::_M_deallocate (this=0xbffff194, 
    __p=0x81dc5e0, __n=4433) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:146
#10 0x0805219e in ~_Vector_base (this=0xbffff194, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:132
#11 0x08050139 in ~vector (this=0xbffff194, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:313
#12 0x0804d32d in NaiveBayesClassifier::buildModel (this=0xbffff28c, maxFeaturesPerClass=100) at NaiveBayesClassifier.cpp:106
#13 0x0805c357 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff3d4) at nbClassifyMain.cpp:15
```

**Edit 1:**
NaiveBayesClassifier.cpp : http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=49445
NaiveBayesClassifier.h   : http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=49446

**Edit 2:**
I commented out `std::sort(ti.begin(), ti.end());` and found the error is gone. Now I am confused how std::sort() works.

Comment: There is a lot of code here that is not visible, making this example not obviously erroneous. Try to provide the code of used functinos and the current function's parametters... give more context.

Comment: please clean up the code a little.. make me want to answer the question.

Comment: It is possible that the problem is with the `term_importance` class. Is it's copy constructor correct?

Comment: The problem may be an out-of-bounds write to a different container, corrupting the allocation information for this vector. I would use Valgrind to track this down.

Comment: Posted the whole code as link.

Comment: That's a lot of code. One thing appears to be wrong from a glance: `bool NaiveBayesClassifier::term_importance::operator<(term_importance ti2) const` does not meet the requirements of the standard library. It is possible that `a < b` and `b < a` are both false (a and b are equivalent), however it should never be the case that they are both true or this operator does not define strict weak ordering (or whatever it is called). Perhaps it has nothing to do with the problem, perhaps it is putting the map into an invalid internal state.

Answer (score 2):

Line 9 of that stack trace leads me to believe that the vector mentioned is doing a double delete.  I would look into the classes you are putting into that vector and make sure they follow the rule of three, or at least set pointers to null after you delete them.

Comment: This is the offending class, by the look of it: NaiveBayesClassifier::term_importance

Answer (score 1):

Run your program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), it should help you diagnose what is wrong.